# html css Vertical list aligning top

Tags: css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a container with 4 columns, on the top theres an image with some text below it.

But it doesnt align towards the top, but bottom

This is the styling for li

```
#carousel-navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: (the images on the bottom should be on the top instead)

http://jsfiddle.net/G6Jnh/

I'm thinking a table might be easier but it should only be used to display data and not layout they say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align` property like following:

```
#carousel-navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23%;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align:top; /* add this */
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6Jnh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Display the `ul` as a table and the `li` as table cells and then use vertical-align as you need to align

```
#carousel-navigation ul {
    display: table;
}

#carousel-navigation li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G6Jnh/2/)

Comment: This is interesting, what is the difference between doing this and using a table? its practical but is it a good practice? Also the display-inline block was overiding the table-cell if you remove it, you don't need vertical-align but must remove padding from the ul

Comment: What counts is the nature of your element (semantics of your HTML code). CSS will just display them differently from their default; it's just about style not their intrinsic nature. So yes this isn't bad practice and is useful (using HTML tables for layout is bad practice as you said and of course you must use them for data)

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` may or may not be useful when it comes to `display: table`. It triggers a completely different algorithm in browsers (adapt to content vs adapt to what the author want)

Answer (score 0):

I added a `float: left` to your styling for the li and it seems to work.